# Sort dictionary of words according to a specific parameter

Tags: swift

I want to sort this words according to it weights. How to do this?

// Here is the Dictionary

```
let words: [String:AnyObject] = [
"a" : [["name":"apple", "weight": "2"],["name" : "ant", "weight": "1"],["name": "animal", "weight": "3"]],
"b" : [["name":"bat", "weight": "4"],["name" : "ball", "weight": "2"],["name": "blue", "weight": "1"]],
"c" : [["name":"cat", "weight": "6"],["name" : "cow", "weight": "5"],["name": "crown", "weight": "8"], ["name": "camel", "weight": "7"]],
"d" : [["name":"dog", "weight": "3"],["name" : "donkey", "weight": "2"]],
"e" : [["name":"elephant", "weight": "2"],["name":"egg", "weight": "4"],["name":"e", "weight": "3"]]
]
```

Thanks

Comment: This is a pretty crazy data structure... you should really replace the inner dictionaries with structs, and then annotate `words` as `[String:[CustomStruct]]`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yeah really, use structs.

Comment: I've tried this.. but failed 

for keys in words.keys {
    var items = words[keys]! as! [AnyObject]
        items.sort {
            return $0(Int(items["weight"])) < $1(items["weight"])
        }
}

Comment: which do you want sorted? The "a" "b" "c" etc? or the objects inside those dictionaries?

Comment: The objects inside the dictionary.

Comment: You cannot sort a dictionary. Dictionaries are unsorted by definition.

Comment: Okay.. then how to do this? Is there any shortest way?

Comment: Yeah... I know, this is pretty crazy.... :) Thnaks @originaluser2. But I'm really looking for a shortest possible way to do this.

Comment: Do you want a unique sorted list? Or a separate sorted list for each list of words?

Comment: If you feel your questin has been answered, please accept an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a much better solution, that nicely stores data in an `Item` struct. It's much easier to deal with this way

```
struct Item {
    let name: String
    let weight: Int
}

let items = [ //has type [String : [Item]]
    "a" : [
        Item(name: "apple", weight: 2),
        Item(name: "ant", weight: 1),
        Item(name: "animal", weight: 3),
    ],
    "b" : [
        Item(name: "bat", weight: 4),
        Item(name: "ball", weight: 2),
        Item(name: "blue", weight: 1),
    ],
    "c" : [
        Item(name: "cat", weight: 6),
        Item(name: "cow", weight: 5),
        Item(name: "crown", weight: 8),
        Item(name: "camel", weight: 7),
    ],
    "d" : [
        Item(name: "dog", weight: 3),
        Item(name: "donkey", weight: 2),
    ],
    "e" : [
        Item(name: "elephant", weight: 2),
        Item(name: "egg", weight: 4),
        Item(name: "e", weight: 3),
    ]
]

for (firstLetter, itemArray) in items {
    items[firstLetter] = itemArray.sort{$0.weight < $1.weight} //"sorted" in Swift 3
}

print(sortedItems)
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot sort the dictionary itself, but you can sort the arrays inside the dictionary respectively.

For convenience a struct `Item` is used

```
struct Item {
  let name : String
  let weight : Int
}

var words: [String:[Item]] = [
  "a" : [Item(name:"apple", weight:2), Item(name:"ant", weight:1), Item(name:"animal", weight:3)],
  "b" : [Item(name:"bat", weight:4), Item(name:"ball", weight:2), Item(name:"blue", weight:1)],
  "c" : [Item(name:"cat", weight:6), Item(name:"cow", weight:5), Item(name:"crown", weight:8), Item(name:"camel", weight:7)],
  "d" : [Item(name:"dog", weight:3), Item(name:"donkey", weight:2)],
  "e" : [Item(name:"elephant", weight:2),Item(name:"egg", weight:4),Item(name:"e", weight:3)]
]

for (key, value) in words {
  let sortedArray = value.sort{$0.weight < $1.weight}
  words[key] = sortedArray
}

print(words)
```

Comment: Map is nicer than the read/edit/write steps that `for in` requires, IMO

Comment: You could replace `words[key]!.sort` with `value.sort` to remove the ugly force unwrap :)

Comment: @AMomchilov Yes, but the result is an array of **tuples** rather than altering the original dictionary.

Comment: Thank you. I think I should change my data structure. @vadian

Comment: Thank you @originaluser2 :)

Answer (score 2):

Given this input

```
let data: [String : [[String: String]]] = [
    "a" : [["name":"apple", "weight": "2"],["name" : "ant", "weight": "1"],["name": "animal", "weight": "3"]],
    "b" : [["name":"bat", "weight": "4"],["name" : "ball", "weight": "2"],["name": "blue", "weight": "1"]],
    "c" : [["name":"cat", "weight": "6"],["name" : "cow", "weight": "5"],["name": "crown", "weight": "8"], ["name": "camel", "weight": "7"]],
    "d" : [["name":"dog", "weight": "3"],["name" : "donkey", "weight": "2"]],
    "e" : [["name":"elephant", "weight": "2"],["name":"egg", "weight": "4"],["name":"e", "weight": "3"]]
]
```

### We need a Word struct

Like this

```
struct Word {
    let name: String
    let weight: Int

    init?(dict: [String:String]) {
        guard let
            name = dict["name"],
            weightString = dict["weight"],
            weight = Int(weightString)
            else { return nil }
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
    }
}
```

### Solution

Now it's just a matter of reducing/mapping/sorting

```
let dictOfSortedWords = data.reduce([String:[Word]]()) { (res, elm) -> [String:[Word]] in
    var res = res
    res[elm.0] = elm.1.flatMap(Word.init).sort { $0.weight > $1.weight }
    return res
}
```

### Test

```
print(dictOfSortedWords["a"])
// [Word(name: "animal", weight: 3), Word(name: "apple", weight: 2), Word(name: "ant", weight: 1)]

print(dictOfSortedWords["b"])
// [Word(name: "bat", weight: 4), Word(name: "ball", weight: 2), Word(name: "blue", weight: 1)]

print(dictOfSortedWords["c"])

// [Word(name: "crown", weight: 8), Word(name: "camel", weight: 7), Word(name: "cat", weight: 6), Word(name: "cow", weight: 5)]

print(dictOfSortedWords["d"])
// [Word(name: "dog", weight: 3), Word(name: "donkey", weight: 2)]

print(dictOfSortedWords["e"])
//[Word(name: "egg", weight: 4), Word(name: "e", weight: 3), Word(name: "elephant", weight: 2)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You show me a better way to do this. :)

Comment: I like that you took the effort of adding that "translation layer", of sorts.

Comment: Yeah it's pretty abominable. IDK what it is about structs that scares people away, but new swift programmers just love raping their code with dicts, arrays and tuples

Comment: @AMomchilov ... I think you meant "wrapping" ;)

Comment: Nope, I did not xD

Answer (score 1):

This data structure is really poorly designed. It makes it needlessly hard to work with. It abuses Dictionaries, force unwrapping, string parsing to int... it's just bad. Don't do this.

Please see my other answer, which suggest a significantly better approach (it'll be up in a few minutes).

```
let dict = [ //has type [String : [[String : String]]]... madness!
    "a" : [
        ["name":"apple", "weight": "2"],
        ["name" : "ant", "weight": "1"],
        ["name": "animal", "weight": "3"]
    ],
    "b" : [
        ["name":"bat", "weight": "4"],
        ["name" : "ball", "weight": "2"],
        ["name": "blue", "weight": "1"]
    ],
    "c" : [
        ["name":"cat", "weight": "6"],
        ["name" : "cow", "weight": "5"],
        ["name": "crown", "weight": "8"],
        ["name": "camel", "weight": "7"]
    ],
    "d" : [
        ["name":"dog", "weight": "3"],
        ["name" : "donkey", "weight": "2"]
    ],
    "e" : [
        ["name":"elephant", "weight": "2"],
        ["name":"egg", "weight": "4"],
        ["name":"e", "weight": "3"]
    ]
]

var sortedDict = dict

for (firstLetter, items) in sortedDict {
    let sortedArray = items.sorted{ a, b in  //"sorted" in Swift 3
        let weightA = Int(a["weight"]!)!
        let weightB = Int(b["weight"]!)!
        return weightA < weightB
    }

    sortedDict[firstLetter] = sortedArray
}


print(sortedDict)
```

Comment: "words.sorted" gets failed. It says sorted is unavailable.

Comment: @Shuvo Ah yes, `sorted` is the Swift 3 name. Use `sort` for Swift 2

Comment: Don't use this. I wrote this as example of how horrid this design is, and how much easier this data is to work with in struct form

Comment: Yes... I am thinking of changing my data structure.